# Rules fired upon fact insert - Drools

Tags: drools

I am very new to Drools, and started with the basics. Here is a setup;

1. Have a few rule files
2. Rules in different files belong to different Agenda groups
3. All the rules operate on the same fact
4. In my Unit Test, I obtain a particular "Agenda Group", set Focus (`session.setFocus`)
5. I insert the fact (**Here is where I notice the rules within the other agenda group are getting evaluated even though the focus is not on them)**
6. I `fireAllRules()`

Shouldn't the rules pertaining to the particular agenda group that is in focus be fired and not all rules from all the groups?

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to have to show the code if you want people to tell you why it's not behaving as you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fundamental law in many Rule Based Systems - especially those that follow Rete or similar algorithms - that the *evaluation* of conditions ("t
when", "left hand side") happens whenever there are *changes* in Working Memory: inserts, updates or deletes. In contrast, rule firing or the *execution* of consequences ("then", "right hand side") happens after `fireAllRules` or `fireUntilHalt` has been called.

The *firing* of rules - more precisely: of activations of rules - can be controlled in several ways. Here, it is indeed the focussed agenda group that limits what can be executed by the engine.

Keep this in mind: **evaluation** is not equal to **execution**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you provide few clarifications please? 1. Did you mean ("when", left hand side") and ("then","right hand side") 2. I understand the evaluations are triggered when there changes to the working memory; but shouldn't the ones for the particular agenda in focus be the ones to be evaluated? How does it effect performance?

Comment: Further, I also noticed that there was an "ActivationCreatedEvent" for the rule that I wasn't expecting. Perhaps some mismatch somewhere?

Comment: Although, I have noticed the "ActivatedCreatedEvent" not being fired consistently for the other rule that is not part of the agenda group in focus.

Comment: Can't say without code reproducing the effects. Although, Drools 6.x is reported to be able to delay (part of the) evaluation, circumstances permitting.

Comment: Sorry for the when/then/else confusion: fixed. - No, evaluation is always independent from focus setting, because this results in better performance *overall*. This is the key feature of Rete. - As mentioned before, Drools 6.x uses a different algorithm, where (I think I have understood this correctly) the advantage of Rete is traded off for delayed evaluation. But my "bottom line" remains valid.